# Which class in Android OS handles intent dispatching?

Tags: android, android-intent, operating-system, dispatcher

I'm trying to customize my Android OS to temporarily shut down a few functionalities triggered by various intents. It's completely safe because it only happens on my device. However I have difficulty find out where the intent dispatcher lives. I've looked at ActivityManager, ActivityManagerService, and WindowManager with no luck. Ideally I hope to find a place like:

```
public void dispatchIntents(Intent i) {

    //my code here
    if (i == Intent.xxxx) {
        //my customization here
    }

    .... // Android OS's own intent dispatching
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Follow `Activity.startActivity`...

Comment: Thanks! I have followed startActivity and found that all activity starting need to go through ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait. So I can stop an activity from starting. I have another problem. I hope to intercept before the moment the status bar was shown. I mean, when I slide down the status bar, no intent was received in startActivityMayWait and I don't know how to stop that. Wonder if you know how can I find the point where I can stop status bar from popping up? Many thx!

Comment: Statusbar or Notification rollup? I honestly don't know, but I'd look for the animation, or search for the root layout in WindowManager. This is pure guesswork on my part, I haven't looked into the source this deeply.

Comment: In StatusBarManager, found it